# Excel VBA returns 'type mismatch' error on .Find function - even though it's searching correctly

Tags: excel, vba, find, mismatch

I'm having a problem that a little googling tells me lots of other people have had, but with a strange exception. I am trying to use Outlook VBA to search an Excel spreadsheet to see if a record exists (and if it does, create an email using the contents of that record).

I'm using the .find() function, but it's returning an error - 13, "Type Mismatch." The curious thing is as follows:

- The error is ONLY returned when there IS a match (I have inputted a searchterm that I know to exist)
- When there is no match, I get the msgbox "No Match" as intended.

So it seems that the find function is actually working, but generates an error when it hits a match. The error is on the line with the .find function. I feel this may be a stupid syntax error or something so any help could be greatly appreciated, but I've been unable to sort this myself. The code I am using is as follows:

```
Dim oXLApp As Excel.Application
Dim oXLBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oXLSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim foundproject As Range
Dim ProjectExists As Boolean
Dim searchterm As String


availcheckinfo.Show 'a userform which gets the public variable availcheckproject

searchterm = availcheckproject
ProjectExists = False

Set oXLApp = New Excel.Application
Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="filepathredacted.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
Set oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set foundproject = oXLSheet.Range("A:A").Find(searchterm)

If Not foundproject Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Match"
        ProjectExists = True
Else
        MsgBox "No match"
        ProjectExists = False
End If
```

Comment: Perhaps your Range declarations should be `Excel.Range` instead?  eg: `Dim foundproject as Excel.Range`

Comment: Perfect! So simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: What else is interesting is that, on my machine, that was not necessary.  I hardcoded `searchterm` and used a test file, but other than that didn't change your code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Range declarations should be Excel.Range instead? eg: Dim foundproject as Excel.Range – @Ron Rosenfeld